# How to Show Message While Running PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

I found below code to launch a scheduled task in Windows' 10 Task Scheduler. It spawns a PowerShell Window while the task is executing, and the task runs as expected. I expected to see the message "Waiting on scheduled task ..." displayed in the PowerShell window while the task was running. However, the message isn't displayed. How can I achieve that?

```
Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "\FOLDER\TASK_NAME";

    while ((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'TASK_NAME').State  -ne 'Ready') {

        Write-Verbose  -Message "Waiting on scheduled task..."

    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running your script with the -Verbose flag ? If not, it might simply be runningn at a higher level. I would suggest you replace Write-Verbose by Write-Host and see what it does ?

Comment: Or add `-Verbose` at the end of `Write-Verbose` command

Answer (score 0):

With PowerShell, it is easy to create an instance of a COM object. In our case, we need the Windows.Shell object from WSH. It can be created with the following command:

```
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
```

Now, we can use our $wsh  object to call methods available for Wscript.Shell. One of them is Popup, this is what we need. The following code can be used

```
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

$wsh.Popup("Hello world")
```

[read more](https://winaero.com/show-message-notification-powershell/)